# Parsing a string to date format in java defaults date to 1 and month to January

Tags: java

I am trying to accept a user input of date in the format like : "2000 hrs, Thursday, July 20, 2015". I will then convert this to a date format to do operations on it. But the convertion from string to date is defaulting month to January and date to 1. Here is the code snippet :

```
    String userDateFormat = "HHmm 'hrs', EEEE, MMMM dd, YYYY";
    SimpleDateFormat userDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(userDateFormat);
    String reference_date = "2000 hrs, Thursday, July 20, 2015";

    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = userDateFormatter.parse(reference_date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Date must be in the format " + userDateFormat);
    }

    System.out.println(userDateFormatter.format(date));
```

The following method block prints :
2000 hrs, Thursday, January 01, 2015. 
Any clue why?

Comment: The year format specifier should `y` not `Y`, from the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), *"Y|Week year Year|2009; 09"*

Answer (score 5):

Because you used `YYYY` when you needed `yyyy` and July 20, 2015 was a Monday. You wanted something like

```
String userDateFormat = "HHmm 'hrs', EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat userDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
        userDateFormat);
String reference_date = "2000 hrs, Monday, July 20, 2015";
```

which then outputs

```
2000 hrs, Monday, July 20, 2015
```

Then [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) Javadoc says (in part)

> ```
> Letter    Date or Time Component  Presentation    Examples
> G         Era designator          Text            AD
> y         Year                    Year            1996; 96
> Y         Week year               Year            2009; 09
> ```

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

```
    DateTimeFormatter userDateTimeFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmm 'hrs', EEEE, MMMM dd, uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String referenceDate = "2000 hrs, Monday, July 20, 2015";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(referenceDate, userDateTimeFormatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime.format(userDateTimeFormatter));
```

Output is:

> 2000 hrs, Monday, July 20, 2015

The [answer by Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33427708/5772882) is correct. I am contributing the modern answer using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. When this question was asked, it had been out for one and a half years. Now it’s four years old and widespread. I am furthermore giving an explicit locale. Your date-time is in English, and while your default locale probably is too, code that relies on that will break if one day you run it on a computer in a different locale or you just change your own locale setting.

You’re far from the only one making the mistake of using incorrect case in a format pattern string. Questions about this are being asked on Stack Overflow all the time. `SimpleDateFormat` is renowned for acting up: it gives you an incorrect result and pretends all is fine, where you would really have expected it to notify you that something was wrong, for example by throwing an exception.

The modern API *does* throw an exception when you give it incorrect input that it can detect. For example:

```
    DateTimeFormatter userDateTimeFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmm 'hrs', EEEE, MMMM dd, YYYY", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String referenceDate = "2000 hrs, Thursday, July 20, 2015";
```

Result:

> java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from
>   TemporalAccessor: {MonthOfYear=7, DayOfWeek=4,
>   WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2015, DayOfMonth=20},ISO resolved
>   to 20:00 of type java.time.format.Parsed

It’s not very readable. The thing to notice is “WeekBasedYear”. A week-based year is only useful with a week number, so it’s wrong here. And [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) will tell you that it was uppercase `YYYY` that gave you this. Let’s fix:

```
    DateTimeFormatter userDateTimeFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmm 'hrs', EEEE, MMMM dd, uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

With `DateTimeFormatter` it’s customary to use `uuuu` for year. `yyyy` works too for years after year 0. We’re not done, though:

> java.time.DateTimeException: Conflict found: Field DayOfWeek 1 differs
>   from DayOfWeek 4 derived from 2015-07-20

The modern API also refuses to accept an incorrect day of week, so you get full validation of your date (there’s a trick to persuade it, though, if you don’t want this validation). As Elliott Frisch already said, July 20, 2015, was a Monday (day 1 of the week), not a Thursday. In my first snippet above I have also fixed this error, so that works.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.