# How do I get a {Zoned,Offset}DateTime from String "06.03.2018 06:00 CET"?

Tags: java, java-time, date

I'm trying to parse a datetime coming from a European RSS feed.  The date looks like this:  `"06.03.2018 06:00 CET"`.  I want a `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`, but I can't convince Java to parse the String.  What am I doing wrong?

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm z");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("06.03.2018 06:00 CET", dtf);

Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2018, MonthOfYear=3, DayOfMonth=6},ISO,Europe/Paris resolved to 06:00 of type java.time.format.Parsed

// seems to be crashing here:  LocalDate.java:363
public static LocalDate from(TemporalAccessor temporal) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(temporal, "temporal");
    LocalDate date = temporal.query(TemporalQueries.localDate());
    if (date == null) {  // <== SOMEHOW THIS IS NULL
        throw new DateTimeException("Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: " +
                temporal + " of type " + temporal.getClass().getName());
    }
    return date;
}
```

The value of `temporal` is:

```
{WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2018, MonthOfYear=3, DayOfMonth=6},ISO,Europe/Paris resolved to 06:00
```

Comment: The problem is `YYYY` it's for week-based-year change your pattern to `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm z`. See [Patterns for Formatting and Parsing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns)

Comment: Thanks @devpuh, that was it.  So obvious too, right in front of me.  Thanks again.

Comment: Near-duplicate of [Parsing a string to date format in java defaults date to 1 and month to January](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427670/parsing-a-string-to-date-format-in-java-defaults-date-to-1-and-month-to-january). That question uses the outdated `SimpleDateFormat`, but otherwise the problem and the solution are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uppercase `Y` represents the week-based year (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) for a detailed explanation), while the year field is represented by lowercase `y`. See the javadoc for details:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns

So change your pattern to "dd.MM.**yyyy** HH:mm z".

Another detail is that timezone abbreviations are ambiguous. CET is used by more than one country, hence it can be mapped to multiple timezones: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cet#tz-where

Some abbreviations might work (aka "doesn't throw exception"), but they'll be mapped to some arbitrary default that you don't have control over. In my JVM, running this code:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm z");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("06.03.2018 06:00 CET", dtf);
```

Produces a `ZonedDateTime` equals to:

> 2018-03-06T06:00+01:00[Europe/Paris]

CET was mapped to "Europe/Paris" (which is some arbitrary choice of the JVM, but it's not a guarantee that you'll always get that). And CET is also used by many others timezones, such as "Europe/Berlin", "Europe/Madrid" and many others.

If you want to control exactly what timezone you want when there's an abbreviation, you can create a set with your choices and use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to create your `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
// set of preferred zones
Set<ZoneId> preferredZones = new HashSet<ZoneId>();
// my arbitrary choice for CET
preferredZones.add(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // date/time
    .appendPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm ")
    // zone names
    .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, preferredZones)
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter(Locale.US);

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("06.03.2018 06:00 CET", dtf);
```

Now the `ZonedDateTime` will be set to the timezone I've chosen in my set of preferred zones:

> 2018-03-06T06:00+01:00[Europe/Berlin]

Comment: On my Java 9 in Europe/Copenhagen time zone I get `2018-03-06T06:00+01:00[Europe/Copenhagen]`. So the result isn’t even the same on all computers.