# Java 8 LocalDate won't parse valid date string

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, datetime-format, localdate

Java 8 here. I have the following code:

```
final String createdDateStr = "20110920";
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMdd");
final LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(createdDateStr, formatter);
```

At runtime I get the following exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20110920' could not be parsed at index 0

    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.
```

...being thrown from the `LocalDate.parse(...)` invocation. **What is wrong with the parser?!**

Comment: Exactly. The whole error message is `Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20110920' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {MonthOfYear=9, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2011, DayOfMonth=20},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed` The "WeekBasedYear" tips you off that the format is incorrect. The OP wanted "y" but wrote "Y". Probably a common mistake. :)

Comment: Same problem as in [Parsing a string to date format in java defaults date to 1 and month to January](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427670/parsing-a-string-to-date-format-in-java-defaults-date-to-1-and-month-to-january), though the symptom is not the same. Yes, a common mistake, @RayToal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An example from [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MM dd");
String text = date.format(formatter);
LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(text, formatter);
```

You should use `"yyyyMMdd"` instead of `"YYYYMMdd"`. The difference between `Y` and `y` was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431882/difference-between-year-of-era-and-week-based-year).

Answer (score 1):

No need to specify the format by hand. It’s already built-in.

```
    final String createdDateStr = "20110920";
    final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE;
    final LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(createdDateStr, formatter);
    System.out.println(localDate);
```

This outputs:

> 2011-09-20