# How To Sort a List By Date & Time?

Tags: java, android, sorting, datetime, arraylist

I've Date & Time string like this

> "Thu Oct 30 12:42:56 GMT+05:30 2018"
>
> "Mon Oct 21 09:13:56 GMT+05:30 2018"

I wanted to sort them in ascending order.

I'm trying to use the following code to do this, but not getting any result.

```
 try {

                    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Model>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(Model lhs, Model rhs) {

                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss YYYY", Locale.getDefault());

                            Date left = null, right = null;

                            try {

                                left = sdf.parse(String.valueOf(lhs.date_time));
                                right = sdf.parse(String.valueOf(rhs.date_time));

                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            if (left != null && left.after(right)) {
                                return -1;
                            } else {
                                return 1;
                            }
                        }
                    });

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed To Sort", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

What I'm doing wrong??

Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing a string to date format in java defaults date to 1 and month to January](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427670/parsing-a-string-to-date-format-in-java-defaults-date-to-1-and-month-to-january)

Comment: What is the type of `Model.date_time`? And what do you mean by “not getting any result”? Is the order in the list unchanged after your attempt to sort?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by my own, it'll be like this.

```
try {

                    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Model>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(Model lhs, Model rhs) {

                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());

                            Date left = null, right = null;

                            try {

                                left = sdf.parse(String.valueOf(lhs.date_time));
                                right = sdf.parse(String.valueOf(rhs.date_time));

                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            if (left != null && left.after(right)) {
                                return 1;
                            } else {
                                return -1;
                            }
                        }
                    });

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed To Sort Matches", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your own solution. You are inconsistent about how you sort two nulls, which may sometimes cause `Collections.sort` to throw an exception. The answer will be more useful if you will explain what change you have made compared to the code in the question and how it solves the problem.

Comment: Also if `lhs.date_time` won’t parse, you are not trying to parse `rhs.date_time`, which in turn leads to further sorting inconsistencies.